# extracting specific information

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I can't find the information, that I need for my program and hope that somebody can help me.
I have the numbers and letters in each line. There are special characters before the certain numbers.
Each line looks like this:

```
12456 t0 45 54 # 36478 t04 # 37489 to4 # 83940 to5 + 63748 nn 00 +374840 bb 009 + 144839 op 45
```

I have to extract the numbers with # and + before them.

And the result should look like a 3-tupel, like this:

(the first number, all numbers with # before them as a list(till space), all number with + before them as a list(till space too, without to4, to5 etc.)):

```
(12456, [36478, 37489, 83940], [63748, 375840, 144839])
```

Are there any regular expressions for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the regex to get values your line is variable string

```
r1= re.compile("(\d+)")
r2 = re.compile("#\s*(\d+)")
r3 = re.compile("\+\s*(d+)")
(r3.search(string).group(0),r2.findall(string),r.findall(string))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question: Why does ("\+\s*(\d+)") work and ("\*\s*(\d+)") with * instead of + doesn't? hm, ("#\s*(\d+)") doesn't work too... only r1 and r3...

Comment: \+ means + character (\ escape character as + is a special character in regex) whereas * can match any character

Comment: yeah, but if I need a * instead of + (I need the numbers like this * 637383 and with \ I want to escape * as a special character in regex) but it does't work : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. Everything ist the SAME, I just put a * instead of + and it doesn't work....

Comment: It should work >>> r=re.compile("\*\s*(\d+)");
>>> r.findall("* 6888 *99999");
['6888', '99999']

Comment: got it looks like you are specifying  ("*\s*(\d+)") instead of  ("\\*\s*(\d+)")

Comment: Use `\`` + code + `\`` to display text as `code` in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a regular expression would be the right tool for the job because of the grouping requirement. I'd suggest the following:

```
in_str = "12456 t0 45 54 # 36478 t04 # 37489 to4 # 83940 to5 + 63748 nn 00 +374840 bb 009 + 144839 op 45"
parts = in_str.split()
first = None
got_hash = False
hashes = []
got_plus = False
pluses = []


for part in parts:
  if first is None:
    first = int(part)
  elif part == "#":
    got_hash = True
  elif part == "+":
    got_plus = True
  elif got_hash:
    hashes.append(int(part))
    got_hash = False
  elif got_plus:
    pluses.append(int(part))
    got_plus = False

print ((first, hashes, pluses))
```

Note that this doesn't print `375840`, because of the missing space

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use three simple regex and the merge the results because for extract an undefined amount of number you must make a global regex with multiple matches on the same line, so:

For the first number:

```
re.compile("\d+")
```

For the `#` numbers

```
re.compile("# *?\d+")
```

and for the `+` numbers

```
re.compile("+ *?\d+")
```